# How to round decimal value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a small project in vb.net. I have a value like 12.13 and want to round it like 13. It should always be the next number to round.for example if I have 22.08 it should round to 23, not 22.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show us in code what you have tried to do and where you're stuck at or any errors that you get.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `Math.Ceiling`, which does exactly that.

Note that it will always round negative numbers *towards* zero.